# Tensorflow Keras Regression model - Biased Results

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras, kaggle

I am trying to implement a Keras Regression model on a dataset for my learning purpose.

I have taken the data from the Kaggle Loan Default Prediction Challenge and I am trying to predict whether a person will default on a loan or not

The target column seems to be imbalanced and majority of the observations seems to have "0" as their value.

I have tried the following approaches to overcome this data imbalance (a) Downsampled the Majority class (b) Upsample the Minority class (c) use the SMOTE algorithm. But these approaches do not seem to help the cause and prediction from the model is biased only towards "0" since majority of the classes in the dataset is "0". I have used the resample method from sklearn for performing the downsampling and upsampling.

What different approaches can I try to overcome this problem and achieve a good accuracy with my model on this data and get a realistic prediction from the model. I am sharing my code

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.regularizers import L1L2
import pandas
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn import preprocessing as pre
train = pandas.read_csv('/train_v2.csv/train_v2.csv')
# Defining the target column
train_loss = train.loss
# Defining the features for the model
train = train[['f527','f528','f271']]
# Defining the imputer function
imp = Imputer()
# Fitting the imputation function to the training dataset
imp.fit(train)
train = imp.transform(train)
train=pre.StandardScaler().fit_transform(train)
# Splitting the data into Training and Testing samples
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split( train, 
train_loss,test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

# logistic regression with L1 and L2 regularization
reg = L1L2(l1=0.01, l2=0.01)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(13,kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu', 
W_regularizer=reg, input_dim=X_train.shape[1]))
model.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: You don't show the code where you're adjusting your samples.  Post that code too, `resample` may not be doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: You've described a classification problem but you're using a regression model. I would expect to see better results with the addition of a softmax and changing your loss function to cross entropy.